# Effects of magnetic field on conductor windings

Tags: analog, hall-effect

I'd like to know if there is any effect inside a conductor while it's **resting** in a magnetic field.
More precisely with the HAL effect, which can only be measured across (perpendicular) to the conductor, is there an effect (change in inductance/capacitance/resistance/frequency response) which could be measured along the conductor (from both ends of the wire), which gets influenced by the HAL effect.

Comment: Any time an electron moves through a magnetic field where the *cross product* of the magnetic field vector and the electron motion vector yields a non-zero result, there will be a force acting on the electron. However, a conductor is an ocean of conduction band electrons and with "normal" currents moves very very slowly. It's there, no question, but measuring it will require some fancy equipment. However, if you use some ***really*** thin copper sheets, I'm sure you could measure it. I'm talking many a few tens of microns thick? Like that. There are calcs you can do to work all this out.

Comment: Even with very thin copper sheets, a quick calc I just made says a hall voltage of "small numbers of microvolts." You'll need good equipment for this, if my envelope calcs are right. I think measuring it will require some serious care in designing as well as building up the experiment. But I think you could actually measure the Hall co-efficient of copper, it's \$R_H\$, with enough care and proper experimental design and tools.

Comment: Sorry, I was kind of off the grid for a few days. Thank you for taking the time to write some words on that topic. To clearify my question I could also add I want to measure the strength of a megnetic field in a coil (get the position of a BLDC @0 RPM). In the meantime I stumbled across capacitive absolute rotary encoders, and there is more information on that topic out there, including proof that pretty precise measurement is possible with reasonable means.

Comment: Sounds like you may have a plan, now. Best wishes! Sincerely meant.